# How to secure the recording of security camera if internet becomes unavailable and device is stolen?

Tags: security

I am considering installing a [Ring](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ring_Inc.) or [Nest](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Google_Nest) camera and door bell. My question is if for some reason, the internet goes offline and if during that time, these devices are stolen as has happened to [other](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hn_McWgfJKU)'[s](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=b_BaQjt4DjM) (but they were lucky that it got recorded).

My question is, if after stealing, when the thief bring these device online and try to reset, will I get the video up to the point when it was stolen? Or the thief will be able to rest and I never get the video of recording as these people are able to do.

Comment: https://www.digitaltrends.com/home/ring-video-doorbell-theft/

Comment: "*How to secure security camera itself?*"  **Security fasteners that can not be unscrewed with common tools**.

Comment: Alaska - I believe his real question is about the availability of the recording if the internet is down and the Ring is stolen.  Not how to secure the Ring or Nest.

Comment: The title of the question is not worded properly and does not reflect what the actual question is. I am aware of the actual question, I just love to  point how how Words are important.

Comment: This is a great question to put to the manufacturer or ask on Amazon

Answer (score 1):

For the Ring, You will be able to get any recording up to the time the internet went down.  Others were able to get to the point of being stolen because the internet was up and the recording is actively being uploaded for any motion.
Resetting and using on a different account does not erase previously recorded motion on your account.  From your account, you will see what  was recorded up to the point of the internet going down.

Comment: thanks, so there is no mechanism in the device that will keep the recording locally stored while internet is offline and upload when internet becomes available

Comment: Not based on the description you described.  Even if the 'store and forwarded' capability existed, your wifi would no longer be available after the theft.  A reset would wipe out any memory of a previous wifi connection.

Comment: with store and forward, when the reset is done, if ring firmware forces that the internet access be set and at that time the ring system can forward that particular recording

Comment: I would guess that the odds are pretty slim that the internet or your wifi would be down at the exact time of the theft.

Comment: You are over-analyzing the problem.  The straight answer is provided in my Ans.  No recording available after the internet is down and Ring is stolen.

Comment: @puzzled What you want is in conflict.  On one hand, you want the most famous, dumbed-down turnkey product.  On the other hand, you want a specialty requirement that's too sophisticated for turnkey/dumbed-down.  You would have to knock this together out of more specialized stuff. Micro-PC running Linux,  and a USB memory stick buried in a wall. You may have to either sacrifice some glitz, or have two camera systems.

Comment: Mind you, if the manufacturer actually paid attention to "who the device was registered to" and refused to register it (reset or not) to a new account without the old account agreeing that it had been legally sold, rather than stolen...oh, but we are talking about one of the most famously hackable hunks of junk in the industry. Nevermind...

Comment: @ecnerwal I was considering Ring and Nest, and I also feel that it could be hackable , can you please point to some articles about so. I could not find much about it being hacked

Comment: I *really* can't think you looked very hard. Go to google, enter: **ring camera hack** and start reading. Made US national news with videos of hackers interacting creepily with children in Dec 2019, at minimum. Many other articles as well.

Answer (score 1):

It seems like a possible concern here is that a thief cuts the wires to the cable internet or cuts power to the house before breaking in and stealing the cameras.

You can address these two aspects by doing the following:

1. Set up a wifi hotspot which uses cellular data (may require an additional cellular data plan) for internet and connect all your wifi cameras to this hotspot. This protects against a thief cutting the cable and stealing the camera before the footage can be uploaded.
2. Run the wifi hotspot off of an uninterruptible power supply strong enough to provide power in the event power to your home is lost (and do the same for the cameras, or ensure they have some other form of battery backup available).